# Error: Unsupported WebSocket version detected: HyBi-00/Hixie-76

Tags: angular7, qz-tray

I'm tried to integrate my angular 7 web app with QZ Tray for printing without a preview dialog. But got unsupported WebSocket version. Please help me resolve it? 
Thanks

```
- Dependencies
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^7.2.11",
    "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
    "qz-tray": "^2.0.10",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.0",
    "sha": "^3.0.0",
    "ws": "7.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
},
```

Now here is what I did

```
import * as qz from 'qz-tray';
import { sha256 } from 'js-sha256';

qz.api.setSha256Type(data => sha256(data));
qz.api.setPromiseType(function promise(resolver) { return new Promise(resolver); });
qz.api.setWebSocketType(require('ws'));
var createHash = require('sha.js');
qz.api.setSha256Type(function(data) {return createHash('sha256').update(data).digest('hex');});

qz.websocket.connect().then(qz.printers.getDefault).then(printer => console.log("Default printer: " + printer))
.then(qz.websocket.disconnect)
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Output Log:

```
utils.ts:414 Error: Unsupported WebSocket version detected: HyBi-00/Hixie-76 at qz-tray.js:667 at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:910) at Object.promise (utils.ts:21) at Object.connect (qz-tray.js:654) at Utils.push../src/app/@core/one.utils/utils/common/utils.ts.Utils.initPrinterService (utils.ts:405)
```

Comment: Do you have the full output log?

Comment: here is full chrome log: utils.ts:414 Error: Unsupported WebSocket version detected: HyBi-00/Hixie-76
    at qz-tray.js:667
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:910)
    at Object.promise (utils.ts:21)
    at Object.connect (qz-tray.js:654)
    at Utils.push../src/app/@core/one.utils/utils/common/utils.ts.Utils.initPrinterService (utils.ts:405)

Comment: This issue come from Socket type. Just remove "qz.api.setWebSocketType(require('ws'));" for resolve this issue

Comment: Hello, I am not sure how you resolved this. I tried removing this line but I am still running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `ws` project with the `w3cwebsocket`.

```
// Node example, adjust to your implementation as-needed
var qz = require("qz-tray");

// Use default Promise provided by JS
qz.api.setPromiseType(function promise(resolver) { return new Promise(resolver); });

// Simulate the browser's version of the websocket
qz.api.setWebSocketType(require('websocket').w3cwebsocket);

// There's a bunch of sha256 libs out there, choose one
var createHash = require('sha.js');
qz.api.setSha256Type(function(data) {
    return createHash('sha256').update(data).digest('hex');
});

qz.websocket.connect().then(function() {
    return qz.printers.find();
}).then(function(printers) {
    console.log(printers);
}).then(function() {
    return qz.websocket.disconnect();
}).then(function() {
    process.exit(0);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```